# keep modal true but without screen fade overlay

Tags: jquery-ui

Part of an ajax code:

```
success: function(data) {
        $('#dg1').dialog({
            modal:true,
            draggable: false        
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to keep `modal = true` option but without entire screen fade overlay when dialog appears?

Comment: You could adjust the `modal` background via CSS to `none` or `transparent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, the modal element has a jQuery UI Class of `ui-widget-overlay`. You could adjust this like so:

**CSS**

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
  background: transparent;
}
```

This effectively makes it clear, yet still there to do it's job.